# GZipping content files in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, gzip

I use the following attribute to decorate my `BaseController` class.

```
public class OutputCompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted))
            return;

        encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that, even though this works just fine for views and every action result, the attribute isn't working for stuff on the `/Content` folder of the project. I was wondering how I could make it so that files in the `Content` folder use a controller, or are bound somehow or hooked by something that allows me to append these filters to the response header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of writing such action filters and reinventing the wheels you could [activate compression](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression) in IIS. You could do this for static and dynamic content.

Comment: But you can't set this in web.config, right? How would you set compression in shared hosting environment?

Comment: @frennky, in this case you should use a custom HTTP module (IHttpModule) instead of an action filter. Action filters (as their name suggests) are intended for actions. If you want to manually compress static files use a module. But in order for this module to be invoked for static resources such as images and javascript you need to configure your application to run in integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: @Darin are there examples of HTTP modules that are used to GZip responses?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of examples. Here's one: http://forums.iis.net/p/1163687/1942354.aspx

Comment: @frennky why can't u set this in web.config? http://am-blog.no-ip.org/BlogEngine/post/2010/11/23/Enable-Gzip-compression-in-ASPNET-using-webconfig-configuration.aspx