# GZip compression from code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gzip

Is there anyway I can do dynamic GZip compression from code, when the module is not installed on a IIS Server ? My hosting company does not want to install this module on the server, still waiting for a reason from them.

I checked locally it can help me allot when dynamic compression is allowed.

kind regards

Comment: The reason btw is that dynamic compression is to CPU hungry, which I can understand, but they should host less websites on a server then to allow us to use common features like this :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using an action filter.

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this attribute to the desired controllers

```
[CompressFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

or as a global filter.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CompressFilter());
    }
}
```

**Note :** for web ressources (Js & Css), I also highly suggest you to use bundling & minification.

Comment: I will try this tonight. I am using bundling for my javascript. Will I be able to use the code above on my bundles as well ?

Comment: A check for Child Action can be added. [Stackoverflow Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067049/asp-net-mvc-response-filter-is-null-when-using-actionfilterattribute-in-regist)