# How to compress JSON responses

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, compression

I am using a lot of ajax calls to query the database and I get large text (json) responses. I will like to compress the response.

There is a great way of compressing text using javascript in [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/294421/637142).

The problem is I want to compress the response on my aspx server and decmpress it with javascript. Therefore I need to run the `lzw_encode` function on my asp.net server. Should I I translate that function to C# or there is another way?

Using the link above if you dont want to configure IIS or change header you can compress the code on the server with:

**C#**

```
    public static string Compress(string s)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        char[] data = s.ToArray();
        var output = new List<char>();
        char currChar;
        string phrase = data[0].ToString();
        int code = 256;

        for (var i = 1; i < data.Length; i++){
            currChar = data[i];
            var temp = phrase + currChar;
            if (dict.ContainsKey(temp))                
                phrase += currChar;                
            else
            {
                if (phrase.Length > 1)                    
                    output.Add((char)dict[phrase]);                    
                else                    
                    output.Add((char)phrase[0]);                    
                dict[phrase + currChar] = code;
                code++;
                phrase = currChar.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (phrase.Length > 1)            
            output.Add((char)dict[phrase]);            
        else            
            output.Add((char)phrase[0]);

        return new string(output.ToArray());
    }
```

and on the browser you can decompress it with:

**javascript**

```
// Decompress an LZW-encoded string
function lzw_decode(s) {
    var dict = {};
    var data = (s + "").split("");
    var currChar = data[0];
    var oldPhrase = currChar;
    var out = [currChar];
    var code = 256;
    var phrase;
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currCode = data[i].charCodeAt(0);
        if (currCode < 256) {
            phrase = data[i];
        }
        else {
            phrase = dict[currCode] ? dict[currCode] : (oldPhrase + currChar);
        }
        out.push(phrase);
        currChar = phrase.charAt(0);
        dict[code] = oldPhrase + currChar;
        code++;
        oldPhrase = phrase;
    }
    return out.join("");
}
```

Comment: The easiest approach to compress the JSON (and any other) response is to ensure your web server is using HTTP compression. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression The link you refer to in your question talks about compressing data in JavaScript so that it takes up less storage space when it is stored on the server.

Comment: Yeah that is probably a more elegant solution. I will give it a try thanks!

Comment: @TonoNam - I've changed the question to match your actual problem. Feel free to revert/edit.

Comment: Thanks sounds much better now!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Within your server-side response object add a header for GZip, like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

Also, you can use the [GZipStream](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jan/23/Building-a-GZip-JavaScript-Resource-Compression-Module-for-ASPNET) class to compress your content, like this:

```
Response.Filter = new GZipStream(Response.Filter,
                                 CompressionMode.Compress);
```

Comment: This is **SUPER** useful, I wish I could give this another +100.

Comment: Can I use if I use JsonResult method: return Json(players, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Karl I also want more details  on how to use `Response.AddHeader` same case as @VAAA trying to make my `return Json` send the data compress

Comment: This answer was related to solving this issue with ASP.NET WebForms, but I will point you to an accepted answer for [how to compress content in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802107/how-to-gzip-content-in-asp-net-mvc)