# JQGrid Showing empty while processing more than 3200 records with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

JQGrid is working fine for records up to 3000 and so with loadone:true , while it comes to more than 3200 it is showing empty grid. I would like to take up with server side paging and loadonce:false. is there any better way to load the data loadonce:true and show some huge amount of data like 20k records? if we are going to use server side paging, we should fetch only specific amount of records from database ? please find my code below and point me if any issues.

**Model:**

```
public class GOALogging
{
    public int SERV_TRANS_ID { get; set; }
    public string ACT_YEAR  { get; set; }
    public string SEAS { get; set; }
    public string RESPONSE_DT { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      return View();
  }

 public JsonResult getRecords()
  {
      List<GOALogging> items = new List<GOALogging>();
      items = GetLoggingDetails();
      var a = Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      return a;
  }

public List<GOALogging> GetLoggingDetails()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACTOLConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000;
        cmd.CommandText = "GET_SAMPLEDETAILS";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();

        List<GOALogging> items = new List<GOALogging>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(new GOALogging
            {
                SERV_TRANS_ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["SERV_TRANS_ID"]),
                ACT_YEAR = row["ACT_YEAR"].ToString(),
                SEAS = row["SEAS"].ToString(),
                RESPONSE_DT = row["RESPONSE_DT"].ToString()
            });
        }
        return items;
    }
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/lib-UI-jquery-css-custom-theme-jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/GOA/getRecords',
            datatype: 'json',
            myType: 'GET',
            colNames: ['ID',
                'YEAR', 'SEASON', 'RESPONSE_DT'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'SERV_TRANS_ID' },
            { name: 'ACT_YEAR' },
            { name: 'SEAS' },
            { name: 'RESPONSE_DT' }
            ],
            pager: $('#myPager'),
            jsonReader: { cell: ""},
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'SERV_TRANS_ID',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            width:1120,
            height:280,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Past 24 hours ACTService Processing Status'
        });
    });
</script>
<div >
    <table id="myGrid" ></table>

    <div id="myPager"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of Maximum length restriction in .Net, you can use below formated code in your controller to go ahead of issue.

```
        List<MEmployee> items = new List<MEmployee>();
        items = getData();
        var a = Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        a.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return a;
```

[Reference link](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2016/02/jqgrid-using-mvc-with-razor-view-engine-in-dotnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have some problem with the size of serialized data. I mean that you have pure ASP.NET MVC problem. Old version of ASP.NET MVC uses very old `JavaScriptSerializer` for serialization which have the restriction described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278956/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539/315935).

I would recommend you to use `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of `JavaScriptSerializer`. If you would migrate to MVC5 then it will be automatically. `Newtonsoft.Json` works much more quickly as `JavaScriptSerializer` and have no such restrictions.

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ProductStore1.zip) you can download the demo project which used simple ASP.NET MVC for editing the data. It uses `Newtonsoft.Json` of cause.

It's recommended additionally to use compression of returned JSON data. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802424/315935) for example.